# Добавить в маршруты диапазон IP с помощбю route add

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование, маршрутизация

Используя команду `route` хочу добавить не определенный IP, а диапазон `172.16.12.0-172.16.12.255`.
Пробовал `route add -p 172.16.80.95 172.16.12.0`
Маршрут добавляется, но не похоже, что цепляется весь диапазон. Если добавляю по одному IP, то пинги идут.
Как добавить весь диапазон или что я делаю не так?

**UPD**

Хотел добавить диапазон шлюзов одной командой. Выяснилось, что так нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Диапазон задаётся маской: route add 172.16.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: Как то не получилось. Писал в духе `route add -p 172.16.80.95 172.16.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0`

Comment: У команды route add есть определённый порядок аргументов: сначала идёт "начальный адрес", потом маска, потом адрес шлюза. 
`route -p add 172.16.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.80.95`

Comment: что то все равно не получается. Ну никак. Что я делаю не так? пробовал `route add -p 172.16.80.95 172.16.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0` и `route add -p 172.16.80.95 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.12.0`. Однако если добавляю маршруты по одному, например так  `route add -p 172.16.80.95 172.16.12.125 `, то все замечательно работает

Comment: Видимо, придётся кропотливо разбирать подробности. Что такое 172.16.80.95? Шлюз? Или начальный адрес диапазона? Ошибки какие-нибудь выдаёт команда?

Comment: 172.16.80.95 это удаленный рабочий стол, к нему я и пытаюсь потом подключиться. Ошибок команда не выдает

Comment: Вам надо чтобы хост, на котором выполняется команда, направлял трафик к 172.16.80.95 через определённый шлюз? Но тогда зачем вам диапазон адресов?

Comment: Каждый день шлюз для подключения меняется. Надоело каждый день их добавлять, хочу добавить весь диапазон и больше не мучаться

Comment: Так не получится. Один маршрут - один шлюз.